# sqlite where clause condition

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I want to retrieve the first twenty items in the database then the second twenty items, as in selection variable as follows:

```
String selection = SQLite.firstTableColumns[8]+">="+0+" and "+SQLite.firstTableColumns[8]+"<"+20;
Log.d("search from db","selection "+selection+"  !!!!!!!!!!!");
Cursor cursor = SQLiteDataBase.query("feedFirstTable",SQLite.firstTableColumns,selection, null, null, null, null);
```

but it returns an empty `ArrayList`.

Comment: If you have set the ROW_ID on auto-increment in your table. Then use the ROW_ID to get the number of data as per your need.

Comment: firstTableColumns[8] is ROW_ID and is auto-increment ,too

Comment: have you try using BETWEEN operator ? is there an error ?

Comment: yes,i've and nothing returns

Answer (score 0):

You can use these queries to solve your problem :

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Cars LIMIT 4;
Id          Name        Cost      
----------  ----------  ----------
1           Audi        52642     
2           Mercedes    57127     
3           Skoda       9000      
4           Volvo       29000     
The LIMIT clause limits the number of rows returned to 4.

sqlite> SELECT * FROM Cars LIMIT 2, 4;
Id          Name        Cost      
----------  ----------  ----------
3           Skoda       9000      
4           Volvo       29000     
5           Bentley     350000    
6           Citroen     21000  
This statement selects four rows skipping the first two rows.
```